# shp2pgsql data appent without gid

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, postgresql

I have a shape file, I opened it in QGIS that has columns in attribute table named

- **CITY_NAME, POPULATION**

and I have a database table in Posqgresql that has columns named

- **gid (primary key), city_name, population, geom**

Database colums are lowercased names, is this is a problem?

And I want to load shapefile data in existing postgresql database table via **shp2pgsql**.

```
shp2pgsql "file.shp" public.cities | -U postgres -a mydb
```

gives error, Why this error occuring I did not understand. I am giving parameters right.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reasons, the geom column is trying to get into the gid column, hence the error.

If the target is an empty table, you can use the -d option to drop the table and automatically create one as per requirements.

```
shp2pgsql -d "file.shp" public.cities | -U postgres -a mydb
```

If the table contains data and if you are not sure how the fresh contents are coming in, it is a good idea to import the shapefile into a new table(using option -c), verify contents and then append the required data to your original table.

```
shp2pgsql -c "file.shp" public.tempcities | -U postgres -a mydb
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked,  but there is new problem now. I am copying temp table into main table. But gid is not auto increament. So I could not insert new data beacause of PK duplication.

Comment: You are probably having a plain numeric field as primary key (gid).